Designing a Two-Party Protocol
I want to design a two-party protocol that runs on two different processes;
each process is one party of the protocol.
My implementation of a Protocol looks as follows:
enum class Role { P1, P2 };

enum class Stage { ... };

class P1Memory { ... };
class P2Memory { ... };

class Protocol {
public:
  Protocol(Party role, ...);
  void next(string message);
  string currentMessage();
private:
  // Primitive private variables ...
  unique_ptr<P1Memory> p1Memory;
  unique_ptr<P2Memory> p2Memory;
  Stage currentStage;
  Party currentSender;
  Party role;
};


next(s) processes message s and updates current{Stage,Sender}.
currentMessage generates a message based on currentStage.
role indicates which 'side' is running this instance of the protocol.
Based on this role, only one of {p1,p2}Memory will be a valid pointer.
My main problem is with implementing next and currentMessage.
They turn into huge switch statements;
handling each case is equivalent to
implementing the logic of my protocol for that stage,
which is pretty involved.
There are two questions I want to ask about this design:

Can I apply a significant improvement
to the very structure of Protocol as shown above?
Is there a solution for handling next and currentMessage
without dealing with colossal switch's?

My current idea for question 2 is
to define polymorphic StageHandler classes,
such that every subclass implements
the virtual next and currentMessage methods.
Are there particular downsides to this solution that outweigh its benefits?
e.g., more tight couplings, more elaborate logic handling, etc.

A protocol is an agreement between parties on how to communicate between each other. As such, a protocol doesn't map well to a single class.
I would split your Protocol class into two classes, one for each party in the protocol because that maps better to the OOP concepts and makes it easier to use in an application.
In a comment you mention that the protocol has stateful aspects and you also mention having a large switch statement. The typical way to make those more manageable is to implement a state machine. I would recommend you look into the State pattern and other ways to implement Finite State Machines (FSMs). Your idea of the StageHandler classes already goes into that direction.

Its really hard to understand what you want to achieve. For me this is caused mainly because the purpose of your class is not clear. Is its main purpose a model of the message situation or a controller that take care of proper execution order? After that you often find a more appropriate name for the class.
The resulting object seems to have different aspects in different scopes, that is not a proper Object in itself and might ruin your dependency tree if you go forward with this.
Focus on the constructor: The object itself can only be build once (where it is P1), than there must be passed a handle, reference, Pointer or even a derived object whatever- making that by design a P2. Think not two but many and you have P1 and non-P1 case in each methods front, not really a messy switch situation and then just use the 2 as the special case.
Also use a type/class for message and the direction is clear.
Use a type for process and you can get rid of the Role enum and have an interface from the protocol on each side.
As you tagged it OOD, think in Objects/Classes and its somewhat easier to find a proper Design-Pattern for that situation. Normally you aren't done if you stuck with one class.
Alternatively think about twin or pair objects that have to be created by a factory pattern if you have a part in your code that is aware of both processes and can pass each side of them. The factory creates them so that there is sending and reciving roles switch in both of them.

The Protocol class is a stateful controller of a protocol; the stateful part is how this object has variables inside. After seeing your answer, I got curious about how using types for processes and (especially) messages can simplify the situation. Could you add some examples to your answer?
Also, twin objects might relieve me of many ifs and switches. I think having an interface that returns a polymorphic object based on the role a process is taking can get the job done. Please bear in mind that by 'processes' I mean separate programs executing concurrently.

I think I got it. Your approach of having polymorphic object with one aspect is structurally aligned with the process as an object as I mentioned. Your interface might be look easier in the beginning, easier event handling. The main task of Protocol as a controller is to handle the concurrent situations in order. Having it on both sides is a model with two controllers: tricky! With twin objectes through a factory you only need to think on one half of the exchange and use "my" and "their" process.
